# Is grout needed before you use a shower?

Tags: shower, tiling

I am installing a new tile shower.  The floor is in and grouted.  The walls need to be done in stages due to time issues.  Is it okay to tile the walls and then use the shower before the grouting is done?  Will the tiles fall off if the mortar is allowed to dry before using the shower?

Comment: Tiles may not fall off but there is a high risk of introducing water into wall and floor system if you use it before grouting

Comment: Are you willing to wait a week for the  tile to fully dry out again through and through, maybe run a dehumidifier in there?

Comment: @Kris the grouting is not water proof. The waterproof layer is usually a membrane behind the tiles. However I agree that you probably should not use the shower - due to soap and fat contaminating the area where grouting will be.